# Count lines , words, characters in C

Tags: c

This code is taken from C Programming by K & R. I am newbie to C programming and i need little help in understanding this code. This code gives me error please help me how to fix it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */
/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n') ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t') state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
        state = IN;
        ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Error :

```
E:\Files\C\main.c:5:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]
E:\Files\C\main.c: In function 'main':
E:\Files\C\main.c:14:40: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
E:\Files\C\main.c:21:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: K & R is older than the first C standard, don't use it

Comment: Take note to use isspace function (ctype.h). It can check all word terminators, such as LF or FF that are not checked in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the value for **c** instead of comparing.

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t') state = OUT;
```

should be

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') state = OUT;
```

And your main function should be like `int main(void)` and put a `return 0` at the end

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning value rather than comparing it:`if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')`, `==` is used for comparison and `=` is used for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

first of all change main function to `int main()`  at line 5.

Also at line 13 try to use `==`  for making it equal in the way shown below.

`if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') state = out;` 
 //you assign a value instead

Also to terminate a program, at the end write  return 0;